# why this proof of the product limit law use the term $\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon}{2\lvert L_1\lvert+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lvert f(x)g(x) -L_1L_2\lvert =
\lvert f(x)g(x)  - L_1g(x) +  L_1g(x) -  L_1L_2| \\
≤ \lvert f(x)g(x)  - L_1g(x)\lvert +  \lvert L_1g(x) -  L_1L_2| \\
≤ \lvert f(x)  - L_1\lvert g(x) +  \lvert g(x) - L_2\lvert L_1 $

Now if both summands on the last line can be made less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, we win. The second term is easy: we choose
$$\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon}{2\lvert L_1\lvert+1}$$

Then there is $\delta_2$ so that 
$$0<\lvert x-a\lvert<\delta_2 \implies \lvert g(x) -L_2\lvert < \epsilon_2 \\ \implies \lvert g(x)-L_2\lvert \lvert L_1 \lvert < \frac{\epsilon\lvert L_1\lvert}{2\lvert L_1\lvert+1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
* (If $L_1≠0$, we could have chosen $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{2 \lvert L_1 \lvert})$;we added 1 to the denominator just so we did not have to consider the two cases separately.)

My question is why it chose 
$$\epsilon_2=\frac{\epsilon}{2\lvert L_1\lvert+1}$$
And what does the comment with the star actually mean, I apologize that I am a bit slow picking up the meaning of this proof. Please give me some example with explaination.

Answer (score 0):

The thing going on is that the author of the proof wants to write out a proof that handles all cases at the same time. For instance the proof could have been organized in this way:

- Case 1: $L_1 = 0$.  We then see in this case that $|g(x) - L_2|L_1 = 0$, so for this term it does not matter how close we make $x$ to $a$ for this term since this term is zero.
- Case 2: $L_2 \neq 0$. We then see that we can put $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{2|L_2|}$ since if we pick $\delta$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$ then $|g(x) - L_2| < \epsilon_2$, as is done above, then we find that the second term is:
  $$||g(x) - L_2|L_1| = |g(x) - L_2||L_1| < \epsilon_2|L_1| < \epsilon/2.$$

---

The point of putting $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{2|L_1| + 1}$ is so that the second case of the proof is basically the general case since we never have to worry about dividing by zero since $\frac{\epsilon}{2|L_1| + 1}$ is always positive and makes sense and it is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2|L_1|}$, which is what we would naturally use in the proof.

Comment: If it is still confusing then let me know... I'll try to explain it a different way.